# How to display filtered data rows as a tooltip in Tableau Public?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

Noob here, I have a table with different entries (rows) per different (repeating) regions.

I'd like to be able to display the data rows filtered - matching that particular region   thanks - so I get those particular fields related to each region as a tooltip on a map. (I know how to build the map)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just dragging the fields you want to Details or Tooltip is not doing the trick?

Putting a measure on a shelf (other than filter shelf) includes that field in the visualization query results -- i.e. applies the chosen aggregation function to yield an aggregate result value for each partition of the data (as specified by the unique combination of dimensions)

Putting a dimension on a shelf (other than the filter shelf) also includes that field in the query results, but since the dimensions define how data rows are partitioned, it can affect the level of detail of the query. You'll notice this often as suddenly getting many more marks in your visualization after you add a dimension to a shelf. If you are familiar with SQL, dimensions define the fields that follow the GROUP BY keyword.

EDIT

Thanks for the addition, @AlexBlakemore. I've never said dragging a dimension would not work, only that it wouldn't work as the OP wanted it to (basically the same as you're saying).

And though everything you said (above) is true, it's particularly not exact when it comes to maps. Yes, dragging a dimension will further partition the data, but it will not create additional marks on a map (unless it has also geographical properties). Rather, the tooltip will get the first occurrence of that dimension, and display data for that only. For instance, if you drag "Product" to details, and the possible values are "Bread", "Coffee" and "Milk", it will probably just show "Product: Bread", and the measures for "Bread" only. So yes, it will partition, but no, it won't create additional marks.

Back to OP problem. What I believe you want is a tool tip with all values of the dimension (in my poor example you'd like to see "Bread, Coffee, Milk"). Tableau does not have functions to aggregate strings yet, so it's hard to do so.

What I would suggest is to create a separate sheet, and just drag the dimensions and measures you want to rows. Then put it side by side with the map on a dashboard, and use the map as a filter. Then, when you click on a country/region/city, you'll see the data of that region on the other chart.

Refer to: http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-filter-actions-dashboards

or https://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/authoring-interactivity

Comment: no, not really, or I'm not doing it right - also, I don't use aggregated values - I'd just need the raw data rows (just filtered)

Comment: Ok, be more specific. Show a sample of your database and what you are trying to achieve (what should be displayed in the tool tip for the dummy database you send)